# Formatting text in C

Tags: c, text, formatting

I need an advice on how to handle this task.
I would like to format chars so that only a given number of characters were on one line. User input would be the number representing the max length of the line. The program would then print the char formatted in a way that words are divided by only one space and when some word doesn't fit in the line anymore, it would be printed on a new line.
Example:

```
char text="Lorem      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer metus";
format(text,20);
```

Expected output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet,
consectetuer
adipiscing elit.
Integer metus
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? How would you do it  with  a pencil and paper? Btw, `char text` should be `const char* text` or `char text[]`.

Comment: @drRobertz does it help with OPs problem?

Comment: If he just wants a solution,  no. If he wants to learn how to solve the problem,  probably.

Comment: @drRobertz does it change anything? BTW he's declaration is 100% OK.

Comment: @P__J__ : The declaration is not OK, and drRobertz comment does not need to help with the problem; that is why it is posted as a comment not an answer. The comment is clearly aimed at improving the question, not at answering it.  No effort "do my homework for me" questions are discouraged.

Comment: I am wtiting about the const which is not needed but of course he is missing the `*`

Comment: There are many ways this might be solved "_easiest_" is a matter of subjective opinion, but on SO it is generally encouraged for you to make a fair attempt and for questions to address issues your have with _your_ attempt.  Avoid questions that merely state requirements and and ask for a solution.  As it stands the question is far too broad.

Comment: @P__J__ : While the `const` may not be necessary for it to compile as C; it is nonetheless sound advice and good practice, and should not be criticised.  C allows it for backward compatibility, not because it is a good practice. You also said "100% OK"; I don't think you can defend the statement.

Comment: @Clifford Yes I admit - did notice the missing star

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very simple implementation. It misses other separators than the space. It does not check for the corner cases like the single word longer than the line length and many others. But I hope that it will show you the direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_formated(const char *text, size_t size)
{
    char *token;
    char *rwstring = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    size_t len = 0;

    if(rwstring)
    {
        strcpy(rwstring, text);
        token = strtok(rwstring, " ");
        while(token)
        {
            if(len + strlen(token)> size)
            {
                printf("\n");
                len = 0;
            }
            printf("%s ", token);
            len += strlen(token) + 1;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        free(rwstring);
    }
}


int main()
{
    print_formated("Lorem      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer metus", 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: revenge DV or something?